# C# Linq from DataTable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a small `DataTable` that contains a number of rows which I am running a LINQ query against.

I am having problems getting the LINQ to display the text that is in the datatable.

When I run it I can get the column name.

I have tried a number of different ways of doing it but to no avail.

Code as follows:

```
DataTable DTGetNarratives = DAL.GetNarrativeList();

var SelectedNarrative = 
    from n in DTGetNarratives.AsEnumerable()
    where n.Field<string>("narr_code").Equals(ClsPublic.NarrativeCode)
    select n;

foreach (var item in SelectedNarrative)
{
    //test1.Add(item.Table.Columns[col].ToString());
    //col++;

    txtLine1.Text = item.Table.Columns[0].DefaultValue.ToString();
}
```

Any help on this would be great.

Comment: Which control do you plan to use to display? You can either set the binding straight to the "SelectedNarrative", or append(+=) to the TextBox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have one `TextBox` but an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. Do you expect a single row? If not, how do you want to diplays multiple records on a single textbox?

You could comma separate them:

```
var allNarrCode = SelectedNarrative.Select(r => r.Field<string>("narr_code"));
txtLine1.text = string.Join(",", allNarrCode);
```

or as multiline `TextBox` use the `Lines` property:

```
txtLine1.Lines = allNarrCode.ToArray();
```

Only the first:

```
txtLine1.Text = SelectedNarrative.FirstOrDefault();
```

without LINQ:

```
foreach (DataRow row in SelectedNarrative)
{
   string code = row.Field<string>("narr_code")
   // the next line is pointless since you're overwriting the text on every row
   //txtLine1.Text = code;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Field` extension method like:

```
foreach (var item in SelectedNarrative)
{
   txtLine1.Text = item.Field<string>("narr_code"); //here
}
```

*(You can specify the column name in the method parameters)*

I am not sure if you really need that since your `TextBox` would be populated with the last row's value.

To show all values in a single TextBox you can do:

```
txtLine1.Text = string.Join(" ",SelectedNarrative.Select(r=> r.Field<string>("narr_code")));
```

Or you can do

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in SelectedNarrative)
{
  sb.Append(item.Field<string>("narr_code"));
}
txtLine1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: But OP has already used it in the query and you're overwriting the text always in the loop.